# SQL issue,challenge

Tags: sql

Say we have two entities:teacher and student.

each teacher has multiple student.

Now I want to:

query for at most 5 teachers,and for each teacher, no more than 10 of his student.

So far this can be done quite easily by:

```
select *,
(
select GROUP_CONCAT('<sid>',students.name,'</sid>') from students on 
teachers.id=students.teacher limit 10
) as students 
from teachers limit 5
```

But that's not the whole story yet.

**AND**

If anyone of the teachers has more than 10 students,should return `true` for that teacher,otherwise `false`

How to do this in SQL?

Comment: please be precise.  what heading should the produced relation have?

Comment: What database would this be on?

Comment: What database is this?  Your `GROUP_CONCAT` syntax doesn't look like SQLite to me, and the latest MySQL GA release (5.1) chokes with a syntax error on your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pseudo SQL:** one row of results for each of the 10 students for each of the 5 teachers

```
select t.teacher_id, s.student_id, 
    case when t2.count > 10 then 'true' else 'false' end
from
    (select top 5 * 
    from teachers 
    order by teacher_id) t 
join 
    (select top 10 * 
    from students s1 join teachers t1 on s1.teacher_id = t1.teacher_id 
    order by student_id) s 
on t.teacher_id = s.teacher_id
join
    (select teacher_id, count(*) as count 
    from teachers t join students s on t.teacher_id = s.teacher_id 
    group by teacher_id)  t2 
on t2.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
```

Comment: I don't think the second subquery is correct (after looking at this again).  It will only return 10 students rather than 10 students per teacher.

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ makes this super-easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Comment: I need to do it on general database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery for every teacher selected.